# How to install wine in MX Linux?

Tags: linux, installation, wine

I am new to linux world . Now I am using MX Linux . When I am trying to install wine from wine.org it show me like this :

```
$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [51.9 kB]                              
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                               
Hit:4 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Debian_10 ./ InRelease     
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster InRelease                                    
Err:6 http://mx-pkg.mirror.net.in/MX-Linux/mx/repo buster InRelease                                
  Could not connect to mx-pkg.mirror.net.in:80 (103.240.105.163), connection timed out
Fetched 51.9 kB in 41s (1,257 B/s)                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
29 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://mx-pkg.mirror.net.in/MX-Linux/mx/repo/dists/buster/InRelease  Could not connect to mx-pkg.mirror.net.in:80 (103.240.105.163), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
kayes@mx:~
$
```

It says  "Could not connect to mx-pkg.mirror.net.in:80 (103.240.105.163), connection timed out"

Please help me to install wine in mx linux .

Answer (score 0):

See the article
[How to Install Wine on MX Linux 19](https://wine.htmlvalidator.com/install-wine-on-mx-linux-19.html).

The article describes how to add the WineHQ Debian repository, to be able to
install `libfaudio0` and `Wine`.

The final command is:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

(I do not copy the other commands from the article here,
since they may become deprecated after a new version comes out of the
Linux distribution.)